# Updating fields from form

Tags: c#

I'm having a small problem with this program. This program is designed to use polymorphism. I have written one base class and two derived classes.

We are supposed to make a base class(bank Account) array and fill that with three bank account objects. We then assign each bank account object a new object using it's overloaded constructor.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
     //Base class array
     BankAcct[] b = new BankAcct[3];



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //This is not getting current values from form!
        int accountNum;
        int atmNum;
        int pinNum;

        an = Convert.ToInt32(accountNumber.Text);
        p = Convert.ToInt32(pin.Text);
        atm = an - p;

        //base class
        b[0] = new BankAcct(name.Text, 500.00M, accountNum);

        //this derived class inherits from bankAcct name, account number, and 
        //the decimal which is the balance assigned to the Account
        //private variables are atm and pin in this class
        b[1]= new SilverBankAcct(name.Text, an, 1500.00M, atmNumber, pinNum);

        //this derived class inherits from SilverBankAcct atm, pin,
        //has one private variable the decimal at the end which is the interest
        b[2] = new GoldBankAcct(name.Text, accountNum, 25000.00M, atm, pinNum, 0.05M);

    }
```

My problem is that when I instantiate my objects in the Form1 Constructor The fields do not update from the form and the current values in those fields are being ignored. I tried assigning the information by accessing properties in my base class and assigning the values from the form there, but the problem comes when I try to update my atm number and pin number which are private variables that go into my SilverBankAcct class, and GoldBankAcct class.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        b[0].fName = name.Text;
        b[1].fName = name.Text;
        b[2].fName = name.Text;
        //do the same for account number which works, but how am I supposed to update atm and pin from the form when I have no access to these variables I only have access to the base class?
     }
```

What would be a better way to ensure that the values being passed along are being updated to the current values from the form when the button is clicked?

Comment: Debug your code ans see what happens... Also please make your life easier and don't shorten any words in the code - i.e. `an` is not very nice name for variable as it is very hard to guess meaning of it. Or `Acct` - saving 3 characters and making non-readable identifiers will not make your code better.

Comment: sorry, I have just edited it.

Comment: It looks like you have a design problem, you have to make all member that you want to access from out side of the class available, only then you will be able to do what are want to achieve. If you don;t expose the members via public properties, its not possible to access them right?

Comment: I have debugged. There are values going in, but those values are the default values I have assigned on the form. Whenever I change the name, account number, pin, those values do not change and the same old values are still passed around to the overloaded constructors. @Alexei Levenkov

Comment: right @seshuk but even if i do make public properties for the atm number and the pin numbers, how am I supposed to access them from my form if those members are not part of the base class?

Comment: sorry, i should have been more clear. You have to put them in the base class. that's what i meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
private void assignPinNumber(BankAcct account, int newPinNumber)
{
   SilverBankAcct silver = account as SilverBankAcct;
   if(silver != null)
      silver.pinNumber = newPinNumber;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Daniel ! the keyword (as) is what I was looking for! I did `(b[1] as SilverBankAcct).pinNumber = p;`

Comment: Using that pattern is a little risky, if b[1] is not a SilverBankAcct (it's Gold or Standard) the  as  operator will return  null  and that snippet will fail.